# Question about the fixed point set of projective involution on $\mathbb{RP}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

**Problem.**
If a projective transformation$\varphi: \mathbb{RP^2}\to \mathbb{RP}^2$ satisfies$\varphi\circ\varphi = \text{id}$,  it is called a projective involution. If a point $P$ satisfies $\varphi(P)=P$, it is called a fixed point.
Proof: For any projective involution $\varphi$,  there always exists a line $l$ and a point $P$ not on $l$ such that both $P$ and every point on $l$ are fixed points of $\varphi$.

**My Approach.**
I think this problem is more like a linear algebra problem.
For the projective involution $\varphi = \bar{\Phi}_{A}$, assuming without loss of generality that $A^2=I_3$. If $A = \pm I_3$, , the conclusion is trivial. Otherwise, from $(A-I_3)(A+I_3)=O$, and Sylvester inequality, we have
$$3=3+r(A^2-I_3)\geq r(A-I_3)+r(A+I_3)\geq 2,$$Therefore, without loss of generality, we can assume that $r(A-I_3)=1$. Therefore, the dimension of the solution space of $(A-I_3)\alpha =O$ is $2$. Suppose that $\{(x,y,z)':ax+by+cz=0\}$ is the solution set. $a^2+b^2+c^2>0$. Then $l:\{(x:y:z):ax+by+cz=0\}$ satisfies the given condition.

**My Problem.**
I cannot find out the point $P$ which is not on $l$. By considering the special case of the line at infinity $l_{\infty}$ and $P(0:0:1)$, I conjecture that another point could possibly be $(a:b:c)$. However, I encountered some issues while trying to prove it.
Fix $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13}\\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}\\
\end{matrix}\right).$$
For any triple $(x,y,z)$ that satisfies $ax+by+cz=0$, we have
$$x=a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}z,$$
$$y=a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z,$$
$$z=a_{31}x+a_{32}y+a_{33}z.$$
Hence $b_{11}-1:b_{12}:b_{13}=b_{21}:b_{22}-1:b_{23}=b_{31}:b_{32}:b_{33}-1=a:b:c$.
So let$$B-I_3=\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1\\
\lambda_2\\
\lambda_3
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a & b & c\end{matrix}\right):=C.$$
Then$$B\left(\begin{matrix}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
a+\lambda_1(a^2+b^2+c^2)\\
b+\lambda_2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\\
c+\lambda_3(a^2+b^2+c^2)
\end{matrix}\right).$$
$(a:b:c)$ is a fixed point $\iff a:b:c=\lambda_1:\lambda_2:\lambda_3.$
$B^2=(C+I_3)^2=I_3$, so $C^2+2C=O$.
Thus, $$\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1\\
\lambda_2\\
\lambda_3
\end{matrix}\right)(a\lambda_1+b\lambda_2+c\lambda_3)\left(\begin{matrix}a & b & c\end{matrix}\right)+2\left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda_1\\
\lambda_2\\
\lambda_3
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a & b & c\end{matrix}\right)=(a\lambda_1+b\lambda_2+c\lambda_3+2)(A-I_3)=O.$$Then $a\lambda_1+b\lambda_2+c\lambda_3+2=0$.
Then I haven't made any progress. Maybe the claim that $(a:b:c)$ is a fixed point is **wrong**.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you say that you have $A^2=I_3$? Shouldn't it be $cI_3$ for some nonzero $c$?

Comment: @TedShifrin We can assume that c = 1 because $\bar{\Phi}_{cA}$ is exactly the same as $\bar{\Phi}_A$.

Comment: I agree for the most part, but what if $A^2 = -I_3$?

Comment: @TedShifrin What you said makes sense, and indeed there are problems with the proof I presented in the first half.

Comment: Nevertheless, in your argument, shouldn't you be considering the factor $(A+I)$ as well?

Comment: @TedShifrin If r(A+I)=1, we can consider $\bar{\Phi}_{-A}$.  Our goal is finding only one line. And maybe I missed a condition in the problem statement: $\varphi$ has a fixed point. If $A^2=-I$, $\varphi$ doesn’t have any fixed points on $\mathbb{RP}^2$, unless we extend the scope of the discussion to $\mathbb{CP}^2$.

Comment: What you just said is false. Think carefully. And, yes, I am suggesting that the fixed point may come from the line on which $A=-I$.

Comment: Of course the fixed point can come from $A=-I$. I discussed if $r(A-I)=1$ we can find a line. If $r(A+I)=1$, we can rewrite it to $r((-A)-I)=1$. $(-A)^2=I$ so we can use the conclusion we got before: we can also find a line.@TedShifrin

Comment: We need to distinguish between linear and projective dimensions. If $\dim\ker(A-I)=2$ and $\dim\ker(A+I)=1$, then you get linear subspaces of dimension 2 and 1, respectively, which give you *projectively* a line and a point of fixed points.

Comment: The point you made is very reasonable. Thank you for your inspiration!@TedShifrin